# UI vs Business Logic in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So MVC is split into the

- Model
- View
- Controller layer

I thought I had a grasp on what each layer does after ready many many pages but I'm still stumped about one area, which is if something should go in the model or the controller.

I understand that Data-storage classes should go in the Controller
I understand that UI modifiers (ie pulling the right model) should go in the Controller

But what about model modifiers. So for example if we take the software shopping cart approach lets say someone clicks on the checkout button, fills out their payment details and its all approved, a postback happens to deal with this.

The postback object needs to

1. Add an entry to a database table to say allow X user download Y software
2. Send a receipt to the user
3. Log the purchase

Normally (on a non MVC) approach I'd create a class to deal with Access-generation of the software table which would call EF to store info. I would have a secondary class to send out notifications and a third class to log information.

Should I still have these classes in MVC and if so would they be classes as the controller or the model?

Comment: That is all stuff having to do with the model, so it is definitely model layer.  But that doesn't mean it should be part of the cart class.  You might have a CartWriter or CartReader to handle the storage of the cart in the DB (or potentially somewhere else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three of the points that you have defined above form part of the model of your application; the controller should be dealing only with orchestration between the model and the UI representation (the view) presented to the user.

Adhering to SOLID principles, absolutely would agree that we are dealing with (at least) three separate components to:

1. persist the data about user x downloading software y
2. issuing receipts
3. logging

There are many ways that you might approach organising the architecture and components to do this. One way would be to have an application specific component/service that depends on these three components and uses them to carry out the operations listed. Then the controller takes a dependency on this component only.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [Russ' great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478738/304832) in a little more detail, consider this:

```
public class CheckoutController
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<CheckoutCommand> _checkoutHandler;

    public CheckoutController(ICommandHandler<CheckoutCommand> checkoutHandler)
    {
        _checkoutHandler = checkoutHandler;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Post(CheckoutViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(viewModel);
        var command = Mapper.Map<CheckoutCommand>(viewModel);
        _checkoutHandler.Handle(command);
        return RedirectToAction("Complete");
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Complete()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The controller is not doing anything businessy at all. It provides control flow for the user. Now, consider you have this dependency injected into the controller:

```
public class DomainCheckoutCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CheckoutCommand>
{
    private readonly IEntityDataStorage _repos;
    private readonly IEmailSender _email;
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public DomainCheckoutCommandHandler(IEntityDataStorage repos, 
        IEmailSender email, ILogger log)
    {
        _repos = repos;
        _email = email;
        _log = log;
    }

    public void Handle(CheckoutCommand command)
    {
        // use _repos to Add an entry to a database table
        // use _email to issue the receipt
        // use _log to log the purchase
    }
}
```

There is some great info on using interfaces + DI like this in [these](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) [three](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) [posts](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=93).

The best part is you can move all of the other code -- the interfaces, domain classes, and other interface implementations -- outside of the MVC project altogether. That way, nothing in the MVC project does anything businessy. It just delegates to interfaces that are implemented by your business layer or other class libraries.

Comment: @RussCam, I copied and pasted it from your book.